# Calling model methods using a variable Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2
```

I have a Catalog model, with the following methods:

```
def current_items
....
end

def sales_items
....
end
```

There are more than a dozen methods, and I would like to do, in my helper, is to define an array

```
categories = ['current', 'sales', ....]

categories.each do |category|
  m = "{category}_items"
  @items = Catalog.m
  ...
end
```

But, I am getting an error:

```
undefined method 'm' for Catalog:Class
```

Any idea if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try `public_send` to call the public methods in class, use `send` if you want to call private methods as well but avoid using `send` if not needed

```
m = "#{category}_items"
Catalog.public_send(m)
```

Give it a try!

Comment: This does not work. As far as I understand it, send and public_send, are Ruby methods that expect the argument you pass to it, to be the name of the method

Comment: So that's what you are doing here right, you said you already defined `current_items`, `sales_items` and want to call them. What am I missing here?

Comment: @RajdeepSingh Missed '#'

Comment: @coyotepoint You'd also need to change `def current_items .... end` and `def sales_items ... end` into `def self.current_items ... end` and `def self.sales_items ... end` because you seem to be calling the method on the `Catalog` (class) and not on any instance of it.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh The missing # was a typo on my part. It still does not work

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario Yes, I omitted the self, but it's there, and it's still not working

Comment: @coyotepoint What error are you getting and from what line? `puiblic_send` should have worked.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario It's the error I list in my question. I think it's not possible to do what I want, as in having a dynamic method name in the Model, and I would have to include a bunch of conditional in it, but I can call it using send or send_public

Comment: @coyotepoint You won't get this error "undefined method 'm' for Catalog:Class" if you have used `public_send`. Perhaps you had a different error? Or perhaps you were still using `Catalog.m`?

Comment: @coyotepoint Just curious, why couldn't you use `public_send`? (if I get you right, you didn't want to use this because you said you'll have to add "bunch of conditional"?) What do you mean by that? Probably there is something I can help regarding that.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario: or they were using `Catalog.public_send(:m)` (or something like that) 

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ahh that's true! Probably that might be the case! :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :-

```
class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.current_items 
    puts "from current_items"
  end

  def self.sales_items
    puts "from sales_items"
  end
end
```

Then call using :-

- if public

  ```
  m = "#{category}_items"

  @items = Catalog.public_send(m)
  ```
- if private

  ```
  m = "#{category}_items"

  @items = Catalog.send(m)
  ```

thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I can do this, no problem, but that's not really what I'm asking.

Comment: But you are asking for same.. you can just read your question again..